# Reorganising CSV with multiple tables in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV that is generated in the following format:

```
"Serial","Long","Lat","Date","VariableX"
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:09",10
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:10",20
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:11",30
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:12",40
"Serial","Long","Lat","Date","VariableY"
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:11",3.5
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:12",4.2
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:13",3.9
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:14",4.1
```

What I want to do is rearrange it into the following format:

```
"Serial","Long","Lat","Date","VariableX","VariableY"
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:09",10,
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:10",20,
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:11",30,3.5
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:12",40,4.2
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:13",,3.9
300,51.5068,-0.0725,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:14",,4.1
```

The way in which I was trying to do this was to search down the CSV finding each occurrence of "Serial" to obtain the row then split these into separate dataframes then to merge them back together by matching the Date column. I didn't get that far but I assumed it would leave any unmatched column as empty.

In R I tried using readlines, I was able to identify the location of each table but I don't think it was correctly picking out the columns of data so then I switched back to read.csv and tried merge but I keep getting the following error: `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`

Comment: Your sample data seems to be missing some sample data. Where are the "Serial" values?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question directly but a CSV file has no business containing multiple tables: one table, one file. Adhering to this guideline makes life **much** easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  `Raw` is a character vector with one line per component.  `is.hdr` is a logical vector indicating which lines are header lines.  `DF` is the data formed into a data frame without the headers.  `varnames` is a character vector of the `VariableX`, `VariableY`, ... names.  `Time` is a character vector with one component per row of `DF` giving the Variable name associated with that row.  Finally we use `dcast` to form the result.

```
Lines <- '"Serial","Long","Lat","Date","VariableX"
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:09",10
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:10",20
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:11",30
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:12",40
"Serial","Long","Lat","Date","VariableY"
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:11",3.5
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:12",4.2
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:13",3.9
300,51.5068,"9/Feb/2014 13:03:14",4.1'

library(reshape2)

# Raw <- readLines("myfile.dat")
Raw <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
is.hdr <- grepl("Serial", Raw)

DF <- read.table(text = Raw[!is.hdr], sep = ",") 
names(DF) <- c("Long", "Lat", "Date", "Variables")

varnames <- gsub('.*,"|"$', "", Raw[is.hdr])
Time <- varnames[cumsum(is.hdr)[!is.hdr]]

dcast(data = DF, Lat + Long + Date ~ Time)
```

which gives:

```
Using Variables as value column: use value.var to override.
      Lat Long                Date VariableX VariableY
1 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:09        10        NA
2 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:10        20        NA
3 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:11        30       3.5
4 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:12        40       4.2
5 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:13        NA       3.9
6 51.5068  300 9/Feb/2014 13:03:14        NA       4.1
```

*REVISED* in light of poster's comments.

Comment: The second example is what I am after, the only issue is that ix is causing VariableY to be placed into VariableX column when X doesn't appear for that time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to get started but it is untested since your sample data seems to be missing some information:

```
## Read the file into R
x <- readLines("~/test.txt") ## Replace with your actual path/filename

## Convert to data.frames and merge
Reduce(function(x, y) 
  merge(x, y, by = c("Serial", "Long", "Lat", "Date"), all = TRUE), 
       lapply(split(x, cumsum(grepl("Serial", x))), 
              function(y) read.csv(text = y)))
```